# Problemas con crontab raspberry

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab, raspberry-pi

Hola tengo el siguiente sh llamado rest.sh (busca matar un programa llamado actu que compile en c y luego volverlo a ejecutar). Cuando pruebo el script funciona correctamente, mata el proceso y vuelve a ejecutarlo.

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    kill actu
    actu
    exit 0
```

lo agregue a una tarea cron que debe ejecutarse cada 5 minutos de la siguiente forma.

```
      5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55  *    * * *   root    sudo /home/raspberry/rest.sh
```

sin embargo el comando nunca se ejecuta.
Alguna idea?, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta sintaxis en el crontab

```
*/5 * * * 1-5 root sudo /home/raspberry/rest.sh
```